# Are tags that are only used once in 6 months auto-removed on SFF?

Tags: discussion, tags

While doing some reading around the tag-related discussions we’ve been having recently, I stumbled across the [“create tags” privilege page](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/create-tags). I knew most of it already, but this bit was new to me (emphasis mine):

> *What happens when a new tag is created?*
>
> The new tag will now be available for all other community members to use, without needing the new tag privilege. It will also show up in the moderator tools new tag report.
>
> However, note that:
>
> - **on some sites, new tags will be automatically culled and removed from the system if they are not used by at least 1 other question in a 6 month period.**

I don’t think it makes much difference to the tagging discussions (the contentious tags are being used quite a bit more than this), but I’m curious:

**Does this rule apply on SFF?**

The [Meta post that first mentions this process](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/48418/226928) sounds like it runs on the trilogy sites, but I don’t know whether it runs here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Nope](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2489/).

> After reviewing [Gilles' data](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/885/automatic-tag-clean-up-and-the-long-tail/2454#2454) and talking about this internally for a while, I agree that *for a site like SciFi* where there are no allowable classes of tags that apply to most questions, this culling isn't helping.
>
> Disabled.
>
> **Please keep a sharp eye on https://scifi.stackexchange.com/tags?tab=new for crap tags.**

Comment: Bad keen posting a link only answer

Comment: Hey, I didn't say 'click this link to find out,' I did provide the key information here. :p

Comment: Given the recent discussion surrounding tags... And the ability to prevent auto-deletion by writing a tag wiki... I wonder if it'd be worth restoring that functionality here.